# Passing a sub-array of objects to chart in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, charts

Using Angular, I'm trying to loop an array of objects to plot different bar charts in the screen.

In my HTML I have something like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5" *ngFor="let sprintCapacity of sprintCapacities">
    <div style="display: block">
      <label>{{sprintCapacity.team}}</label>
      <canvas baseChart
              [datasets]="barChartData"
              [labels]="barchartLabels"
              [options]="barChartOptions"
              [legend]="barChartLegend"
              [chartType]="barChartType">
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I'm already inside a ngFor loop to feed the charts (I'm going to have as much as charts in the screen depending on the number of teams registered). The problem is, now, passing an array of values that is  inside my sprintcapacities object to every property, for example, passing the list of names only (which is an array inside my object) to property barchartLabels.

The structure of object:

```
private sprintCapacities: SprintCapacity[] = [
    new SprintCapacity('Team 01', 'sprint 01', [
      new Member('John', 80, 30, 50),
      new Member('Scot', 70, 30, 30),
      new Member('Anitha', 80, 20, 20)
    ]
    ),
    new SprintCapacity('Team 02', 'sprint 01', [
      new Member('Paul', 70, 30, 50),
      new Member('Raj', 60, 30, 30),
      new Member('Ben', 60, 20, 20)
    ]
    )
  ];
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code one way could be to have helper functions that takes a team and return the datasets and labels for each chart. Something like this,

*component.html*

```
<canvas baseChart
  [datasets]="getBarChartData(sprintCapacity)"
  [labels]="getBarchartLabels(sprintCapacity)"
  [options]="barChartOptions"
  [legend]="true"
  [chartType]="bar">
</canvas>
```

*component.ts*

```
getBarChartData(sprintCapacity: SpringCapacity): Array<{data:string, label:string}> {
    const dataAttr1 = sprintCapacity.getMembers().map(m => m.getAttr1());
    const dataAttr2 = sprintCapacity.getMembers().map(m => m.getAttr2());
    const dataAttr3 = sprintCapacity.getMembers().map(m => m.getAttr3());
    return [
        { data: dataAttr1, label: 'Attr1' },
        { data: dataAttr2, label: 'Attr2' },
        { data: dataAttr3, label: 'Attr3' }
    ];
}

getBarChartLabels(sprintCapacity: SprintCapacity): string[] {
    return sprintCapacity.getMembers().map(m => m.getName());
}
```

I am assuming many things here, like some methods for the classes to obtain attributes, but I think is pretty clear. I also assume that the options, legend and type of the charts are the same for every chart.